# jQuery fails to detect chrome as webkit?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have used `$.browser.webkit` to detect if my browser is either Safari/Chrome, now this check returns `false` when using Chrome ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.browser` is deprecated, and you should use [$.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) instead to check for available features and not specific browsers!

`$.browser` is still available in jQuery 1.8, but will return `Chrome` in chrome browsers etc. and no longer returns `webkit`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SLZNS/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that change in 1.8 !